# Xcode 6 permission error on brand new project

Tags: xcode6

On a fresh created Sprite Kit project I cannot remove the Spaceship asset because of a file permission error:

> You do not have permission to move the file "Spaceship.imageset" to
>   the trash.

I tried the following with no success:

- clear derived data
- clean project
- change permissions in finder

Ok. I tried to continue by creating a new image assets and exporting a png file on it. But another error come when I drag & drop this png file to asset container:

> You do not have permission to move the file "tuileTest@3x.png" to the
>   trash.

This is a weird message because the operation asked was not to move the file to the trash.

So I cannot do anything on a fresh created project!

Xcode 6.3.2

Answer (score 0):

1. open Disk Utility
2. Select your drive with located project
3. Click Repair Disk Rights

Comment: The project is not located on the system partition so Repairing Disk Rights is not relevant. Thank you for your help anyway!